# The 'Effective C++' warnings in MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, warnings, effective-c++

MinGW has this option you can enable that shows warnings suggested by Scott Meyers' *Effective C++*. I don't have the book, nor can I easily get a copy of it, nor do I have the time now to read it, so my question is, what exactly are these "Meyers warnings"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

> `-Weffc++` (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>
> > Warn about violations of the following style guidelines from Scott Meyers' Effective C++ book:
> >
> > - **Item 11**: Define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for classes with dynamically allocated memory.
> > - **Item 12**: Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors.
> > - **Item 14**: Make destructors virtual in base classes.
> > - **Item 15**: Have `operator=` return a reference to `*this`.
> > - **Item 23**: Don't try to return a reference when you must return an object.
> >
> > Also warn about violations of the following style guidelines from Scott Meyers' More Effective C++ book:
> >
> > - **Item 6**: Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operators.
> > - **Item 7**: Never overload `&&`, `||`, or `,`.
> >
> > When selecting this option, be aware that the standard library headers do not obey all of these guidelines; use `grep -v` to filter out those warnings.